# How do I convert `str` object to `datetime` object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a string in this format: `2019-06-18T11:00:10.499378622Z`. I am trying to convert this into a datetime object.

I have tried

```py
s_datetime = datetime.strptime(s_datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%d*%H:%M:%S*')
```

```py
import datetime.datetime
s_datetime = datetime.strptime(s_datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%d*%H:%M:%S*')

Getting ValueError as the regex does not match
```

Comment: Highly recommend the arrow package as a replacement for datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get this error, so I made a little function to use whenever I deal with ISO times.

```py
def ISOtstr(iso):

    dcomponents = [1,1,1]
    dcomponents[0] = iso[:4]
    dcomponents[1] = iso[5:7]
    dcomponents[2] = iso[8:10]
    tcomponents = [1,1,1]
    tcomponents[0] = iso[11:13]
    tcomponents[1] = iso[14:16]
    tcomponents[2] = iso[17:19]
    d = dcomponents
    t = tcomponents
    string = "{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}".format(d[0],d[1],d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2])
    return string
```

Convert your ISO to a string:

```py
string = '2019-06-18T11:00:10.499378622Z'
date_string = ISOtstring(string)
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#Output
#datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 18, 11, 0, 10)
```

There is most likely a better way to do it. But I use this whenever dealing with ISO strings.

If your using it frequently you could make this a separate function:

```py
def ISOtdatetime(iso):
  date_string = ISOtstring(iso)
  date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  return date_obj
```

Just realized I had some meaningless code in there from when I first created the function. They have been removed.

Comment: thanks a lot, you saved my day @jedkea!

Answer (score 0):

I also got an error with your input especially on the unit of `second`. But when I changed your unit of `second` a little bit, it works. So, I have no idea about this.

```
from datetime import datetime

s_datetime = datetime.strptime('2019-06-18T11:00:10.499378Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print(s_datetime)
print(type(s_datetime))
```

Output:

```
2019-06-18 11:00:10.499378
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: I am still having trouble with it :/
`ValueError: time data '2019-06-18T15:08:46.131737185Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'